# How to pass by items by value from an array to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, return-value

I'm trying to loop through an array "fSel.sI", and based on the data inside, pass them as values (not reference) on to a number of function declarations. Right now the problem is that mydrag contains a reference, and as draggable gets called it uses the last array item data. Hence when start: drag: stop: is called, the values are not unique. Help?

```
makeDraggable : function() {
        // create new draggable
        for (var i = 0; i < fSel.sI.length; i++) {
            mydrag = fSel.sI[i];
            $("#" + mydrag).draggable({
                cancel: [''],
                distance: 5,
                containment: "#fWorkspace",
                handle: mydrag,
                start: function() { dragRegister(mydrag)},
                drag: function() { dragItems(mydrag)},
                stop: function() { dragStop(mydrag)}
            });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [look into closures](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#48).

Try the following code:

```
makeDraggable : function() {
        // create new draggable
        for (var i = 0, l = fSel.sI.length, sI = fSel.sI; i < l; i++) {
                var mydrag = sI[i];
                (function(mydrag) {
                            $("#" + mydrag).draggable({
                                    cancel: [''],
                                    distance: 5,
                                    containment: "#fWorkspace",
                                    handle: mydrag,
                                    start: function() { dragRegister(mydrag); },
                                    drag: function() { dragItems(mydrag); },
                                    stop: function() { dragStop(mydrag); }
                            });
                })(mydrag);
         }
},
```

Your problem is with the `start`, `drag`, and `stop` functions. They don't execute immediately; by the time they do, `mydrag` has been set to another value. By wrapping a self-executing function around the code block containing these functions, we create a closure, where `mydrag` doesn't change.

**Note:** For performance reasons, when accessing properties of an object more than once, it's best to create a variable that references (or holds) the property. In your `for` loop, I've created two variables `l` and `sI` that store `fSel.sI.length` and `fSel.sI` (respectively) so that JavaScript doesn't have to look up the `sI` and `length` properties every time around the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your creating a closure. Try this instead

```
makeDraggable : function() {
        // create new draggable
        for (var i = 0; i < fSel.sI.length; i++) {
                mydrag = fSel.sI[i];
                $("#" + mydrag).draggable({
                        cancel: [''],
                        distance: 5,
                        containment: "#fWorkspace",
                        handle: (function(mydrag){return mydrag;}(mydrag)),
                        start: (function(mydrag){return function() { dragRegister(mydrag)};}(mydrag)),
                        drag: (function(mydrag){return function() { dragItems(mydrag)};}(mydrag)),
                        stop: (function(mydrag){return function() { dragStop(mydrag)};}(mydrag))
                });
        }
    },
```

Take a look at this video to understand the powerful and usefulness of Javascript closures: http://vimeo.com/1967261

Comment: See Steve's comment for a better way of doing this :)